# Can a sum of commutators of selfadjoint bounded operators be a multiple of the identity?

Tags: oa.operator-algebras, hilbert-spaces

Let $H$ be an infinite-dimensional Hilbert space, and $a_1,b_1,\ldots,a_k,b_k$ be bounded selfadjoint operators on $H$. Can the sum $\sum_{i=1}^k[a_i,b_i]$
be a (pure imaginary) multiple of the identity ?

I know a result of Halmos which says that the identity is the sum of two commutators, but they  are of the form $[P,P^\dagger]$ so cannot fit the bill.

Comment: No. $[a,b]^*=-[a,b]$ for $a,b$ bounded selfadjoint.

Comment: @LiviuNicolaescu Yes, the sum will be anti-selfadjoint, so it could be equal to i times the identity.

Comment: Oops! You're right.

Answer (score 2):

Yes. Indeed, for self-adjoint $a,b$, the commutator $[a,b]$ is equal to $\frac{i}{2}[p,p^*]$ for $p=a+ib$. So the theorem by Halmos [that you refer to](https://www.jstor.org/stable/2372081) (every hermitian operator is a sum $[p_1,p_1^*]+[p_2,p_2^*]$ for bounded operators $p_1,p_2$) implies that every anti-hermitian operator $X$ is a sum of $[a_1,,b_1]+[a_2,b_2]$ for self-adjoint operators.

Comment: Oh, of course ! Thank you !

Answer (score 1):

I think that in general, it depends on the algebra of the operators.
If for example your operators span some Lie algebra, then no it cannot happen. Since then, the commutators will be primitive elements (with regards to the hopf structure of the universal enveloping algebra), and thus their sum will also be primitive, which a multiple of identity cannot be.

But for an arbitrary set of operators, i do not know.

Comment: Very interesting ! As it happens, they belong to a Jordan algebra A. In that case A+[A,A] is a Lie algebra. Does your answer still apply ?

Comment: @Fabien, i am not sure. How is A+[A,A] a lie algebra ? Is there some reference to see how this works?

Comment: The reason is the formula $[[a,b],x]=[L_a,L_b]x$ where $L_a$ is the Jordan multiplication by $a$. To see that $[[a,b],[c,d]]$ is in $[A,A]$, you first use Jacobi's identity then the above formula.